# What to expect from cuda perfomance

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I've recently wrote some simple code using cuda but although I've heard it can speed things up I don't see much.
for example I wrote 2 code with cuda (without using any libraries such as NPP and ...).

first a blur-filter (without texture memory).

second a fuzzy based segmentation (including some per-element multiply,add,divide and some summations for which I used sample codes from dot-product and a somewhat blur-filter).

but in first case my code was a bit slower!!! than similar OpenCV code and the second one gave me only 2x speed up.

my system (Intel core i7 4700HQ 2.4GHz and Geforce GT 750m)(N46JV ASUS laptop)
and I'm using Visual Studio 2015, Cuda 8, OpenCV 3.1 in windows 10.

my codes give me the results and logically are correct.

my question is should I expect more from my system?

I also used some NPP codes but it didn't change anything they were even a tad slower than my own code (for reduction)

I asked some people before and this is my last hope!

for example a summation code:

```
__global__ void GF3_kernel(double* oldU_temp,
int width,
int height,
double* d_partial_sum_t) {
__shared__ double L[nthreadsGF3];

//Initialize shared memory:
L[threadIdx.x] = 0;
__syncthreads();


//calculate pixel coordinates
const int tid_in = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int tid_test = tid_in;

const int cacheXIndex = threadIdx.x;

//temperory sum
double temp = 0;


tid_test = tid_in;
//power random pixels of thread
while (tid_test < width * height) {
    temp += oldU_temp[tid_test];
    tid_test += gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
}
L[cacheXIndex] = temp;
__syncthreads();

int p_idx = blockDim.x / 2;
while (p_idx != 0) {
    if (cacheXIndex < p_idx) {
        L[cacheXIndex] += L[cacheXIndex + p_idx];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    p_idx /= 2;
}
if (cacheXIndex == 0) {
    d_partial_sum_t[blockIdx.x] = L[0];
}
}
```

and the kernel call would be:

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// sum /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    GF3_kernel << <gridGF3, nthreadsGF3 >> >(d_oldU_temp, width, height, d_partial_sum_t);


    // copy for final summation in cpu
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(partial_sum_t, d_partial_sum_t, gridGF3 * sizeof(double),     cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    //Summation result
    sum_temp = 0;
    //calculate Summation
    for (int j = 0; j < gridGF3; j++) {
        sum_temp += partial_sum_t[j];
    }
```

somthing like that.

what do you think?

the image is a 1 channel image of size 390x390 pixels

Comment: Software development for GPGPU is much more complicated than regular development due to (at least) one instruction - multiple data model and some non-obvious features of memory access. Try writing something easier as your first example, you should see the speed up.

Comment: The speedup depends heavily on your implementation, since the algorithms need to be changed in favor of parallel processing. Also, some time gets lost when data is copied from CPU to GPU and then back from GPU to CPU. So GPGPU will pay off when you process rather big big data sets.

Comment: in addition to all the other remarks (gpu programming isn't trivial etc.) you'll have to take care of the actual task you use to test. Here for example, the image size matters. For small images, CPU might be faster than GPU, because you'll need some good amount of work to perform to overcome the initial offset drawback from gpu: http://mcclanahoochie.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/cv-versus-jkt.png taken from http://mcclanahoochie.com/blog/2011/09/opencv-vs-libjacket-gpu-sobel-filtering/

Comment: I know, I only have input data and output being copied. and also in reduction I send the final part for summation to cpu

Comment: @Micka I tested my code for various image sizes but the time scales in CPU and GPU almost the same

Comment: post your cuda code ;) In your CPU code, are you using IPP or sth.?

Comment: One big problem is that you are using double precision - most GPUs have very poor performance with double precision - try using `float` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect miracles from the GPGPU computig. If you compare the floating point peak performance of high end cpus and gpus you get a factor around 4 to 10 depending on the precision.
If you manage to use your CPU in an somewhat efficient manner, you can expect that you can achieve this as a speedup, if you can utilize the gpu to its full potential. And that is quiete hard. First of all, not all problems are nice for the massive parallel gpu architecture and second optimizing gpu code is hard.

If you want to try to squeze more performance out of your gpu, try to optimize your memory access. Thats the point, where you will loose most of the performance.
Unaligned access and random access in global memory will cost you more than 90% of your performance. Try to allign the data and cache it in the shared memory where you can. That will bring you a long way.
One more trick is to make the kernels use less registers. Generally speaking, the less registers per thread are used, the more can be scheduled simultaneously on one streaming multiprocessor.

```
__global__ void GF3_kernel(
double* oldU_temp,
int width,
int height,
double* d_partial_sum_t) {
__shared__ double L[nthreadsGF3];

//Initialize shared memory:
L[threadIdx.x] = 0;
__syncthreads(); //__syncthreads does hurt performance. Use it if absolutly needed


//calculate pixel coordinates

//const int tid_in = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; //not needed
int tid_test = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

//const int cacheXIndex = threadIdx.x; // not needed

//temperory sum
double temp = 0;


//tid_test = tid_in; //unneeded assignment
//power random pixels of thread
const int endRange = width * height; //most likely done by compiler, but just in case its not.
const int step = gridDim.x * blockDim.x; //same here
while (tid_test < endRange) {
    temp += oldU_temp[tid_test]; // aligned access in global memory is fine
    tid_test += step;
}
L[cacheXIndex] = temp;
__syncthreads();


// This looks like an reduction to me
// Looks fine but there is some potential
// https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwik5IO7nOzRAhWDDRoKHVUuC0kQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.download.nvidia.com%2Fcompute%2Fcuda%2F1.1-Beta%2Fx86_website%2Fprojects%2Freduction%2Fdoc%2Freduction.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFZmgdihbG17glvRmF-zPHfmUR4Aw&sig2=Yil-X_Byf6T6_dKAtN80Aw
int p_idx = blockDim.x / 2;
while (p_idx != 0) {
    if (cacheXIndex < p_idx) {
        L[cacheXIndex] += L[cacheXIndex + p_idx];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    p_idx /= 2;
}
if (cacheXIndex == 0) {
    d_partial_sum_t[blockIdx.x] = L[0];
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. 1) could you give more info about unaligned access to global memory. and I wrote what functions I'm trying to use. do you think GPU is a good way to do them. and if you wanted to write them did you expect more from this system with cuda

Comment: The blur filter is basically a convolution that can be solved with different shortcuts. The blur filter is most likely seperable and therefore can be solved in 1d over columns and rows.
Most likely it would be even faster to use fast fourier transformation before the convolution. I bet, that at least one of those tricks is implemented in opencv.

Comment: If your filter is small, you can load it in shared memory completly. The image should be aligned nice for column wise access. The tricky bit is the access to the resulting image, which is pretty random. You should buffer chunks of it in the shared memory and write it back as soon as the block of the result is complete.

Comment: I wrote my blur filter exactly that way. by the way I didn't use texture memory I have some problem using that

Comment: I didn't use shared memory in this case opencv use 1d over column and rows

Comment: You can forget about the texture memory. It's just a pain to use and does not provide performance boosts.
The only reason to use it, is the built in hardwere interpolation between two points in the texture.

Comment: thanks but the zero intialization was needed I think because they are being counted in summation